# do.call 20% slower than a normal call in R?

Tags: r, function-call

I am not sure if I use the `do.call` the right way:

```
test <- function(test) {
  string <- deparse(substitute(test))
  start <- regexpr("\\(", string)
  end <- regexpr(")", string) - 1
  distribution <- substr(string, 0, start-1)
  string.arguments <- substr(string, start+1, end)
  v <- read.table(text=unlist(strsplit(string.arguments, ",")))
  list.arguments <- lapply(t(v), function(x) x)

  for (i in 1:1000000) {
    do.call(distribution, list.arguments)
  } 
}
```

The goal here is to be able to send a distribution, such as `rnorm` and `rgamma`, followed by arguments to a function, instead of an evaluated function.

Here is a comparison of using do.call and just simply calling the function:

```
> system.time(test(rnorm(100, 1, 10))) 
   user  system elapsed 
   17.772   0.000  17.820 
> system.time(for(i in 1:1000000) { rnorm(100,0,1)} )
   user  system elapsed 
   13.940   0.004  14.015
```

The question is twofold:

- Does do.call really have to take 20% longer?
- Is this the right approach to accept varying distributions and arguments?

Comment: do `Rprof(); for(i in 1:1e6) do.call(rnorm, list(100)); Rprof(NULL); summaryRprof()` and replace the function with `for(i in 1:1e6) rnorm(100)` and run again. You'll see the time due to `do.call` function call overhead (1e6 times).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`do.call` is always going to be slower than calling a function directly, because it has to go through your arguments and find the function before calling it. The degree to which it's slower depends on how much additional computation it has in which to amortise this overhead.

```
> system.time(for(i in 1:1e6) do.call(rnorm, list(100)))
   user  system elapsed 
  13.55    0.00   13.58 
> system.time(for(i in 1:1e6) rnorm(100))
   user  system elapsed 
  11.40    0.00   11.42
```

whereas:

```
> system.time(for(i in 1:1e2) do.call(rnorm, list(1e6)))
   user  system elapsed 
   9.14    0.00    9.15 
> system.time(for(i in 1:1e2) rnorm(1e6))
   user  system elapsed 
   9.14    0.00    9.14
```

In addition, some of your slowdown is due to your regex'ing and other string manipulation which is unrelated to how fast `do.call` inherently is. While fast because it's running on trivially small input, it's still needlessly complicated. Why not just do this:

```
test <- function(distrib, ..., N=1e6)
lapply(seq(N), function(x) distrib(...))

test(rnorm, 100, 1, 10)
```

or this:

```
test <- function(call, N=1e6)
{
    call <- substitute(call)
    lapply(seq(N), function(...) eval.parent(call))
}

test(rnorm(100, 1, 10))
```

Comment: This is not true: in your situation it still takes roughly 20% more time.

Comment: The regexp stuff takes 670 micro seconds on average.

Comment: Was too hasty. Fixed up now.

Comment: That's more like it :-) Thanks!